# Corruption Of Heap

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In my program i got "corruption of heap" error

"Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Project_Name.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in JPS.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Project_Name.exe has focus.
The output window may have more diagnostic information."

Here are the codes:

Header.h

```
#pragma once

#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class ClientInfo
{
public:
int dayM;
string monthM;
int dayL;
string monthL;
string fName, lName;
double itmAmt;
ClientInfo* next;
};

class Record
{
private:
int numOfClients;
public:
int returnNumOfClients();
ClientInfo* head;
Record();
Record* InitializeRecord();
char* CalculateMaturity();
string ViewClient();
Record*  FindName(string nn, ClientInfo *xxx);
void SaveRecord(ClientInfo* h);
double ComputeBalance(double amount, string mnthL, int dyL, string mnthM, int dyM);
ClientInfo* AddClient(string fn,string ln,string xMonthL, int xDayL, string    
    xMonthM, int xDayM ,double xItemAmt);
ClientInfo* SearchClient(string n);
void RemoveItem(ClientInfo* h, ClientInfo* rc, string remfname);
bool CheckExistence(ClientInfo* hx, string fnx, string lnx);

template <typename T>
string numToStr ( T num )
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << num;
    return ss.str();
}
};

Record::Record():numOfClients(0),head(NULL)
{
}

Record* Record::FindName(string nn, ClientInfo * xxx)
{
ClientInfo* newci = new ClientInfo();
Record* newrec = new Record();
ClientInfo* node= xxx;
do{
    if(node->lName==nn)
    {

        newrec->head=newrec->AddClient(node->fName, 
            node->lName, 
            node->monthL,
            node->dayL,
            node->monthM,
            node->dayM,node->itmAmt);

    }
    node=node->next;
}while(node!=NULL);

return newrec;
}

int Record::returnNumOfClients()
{
return numOfClients;
}

void Record::SaveRecord(ClientInfo* h)
{
Record *rec = new Record();
ClientInfo* saveRec = h;
string str;

vector<string> v;
ofstream outF;
outF.open("Record.txt");

if(saveRec!=NULL)
{
    do
    {
        str = saveRec->fName+'-'+saveRec->lName+'-'+
            rec->numToStr(saveRec->monthL)+'-'+
            rec->numToStr(saveRec->dayL)+'-'+
            rec->numToStr(saveRec->monthM)+'-'+
            rec->numToStr(saveRec->dayM)+'-'+
            rec->numToStr(saveRec->itmAmt);

        saveRec = saveRec->next;

        v.push_back(str);
    }
    while(saveRec != NULL);


    for(vector<string>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        if( it != v.begin())
            outF<<'\n';
        outF<< *it;
    }
}
else
    numOfClients=0;

outF.close();

}

char* Record::CalculateMaturity()
{
try
{
    ClientInfo* saveRec = new ClientInfo();
    Record* rec = new Record();
    string str;

    stack<string> month;
    month.push("December");
    month.push("November");
    month.push("October");
    month.push("September");
    month.push("August");
    month.push("July");
    month.push("June");
    month.push("May");
    month.push("April");
    month.push("March");
    month.push("February");
    month.push("January");
    month.push("December");
    month.push("November");
    month.push("October");
    month.push("September");
    month.push("August");
    month.push("July");
    month.push("June");
    month.push("May");
    month.push("April");
    month.push("March");
    month.push("February");
    month.push("January");

    stack<string> mnth;
    mnth.push("December");
    mnth.push("November");
    mnth.push("October");
    mnth.push("September");
    mnth.push("August");
    mnth.push("July");
    mnth.push("June");
    mnth.push("May");
    mnth.push("April");
    mnth.push("March");
    mnth.push("February");
    mnth.push("January");
    mnth.push("December");
    mnth.push("November");
    mnth.push("October");
    mnth.push("September");
    mnth.push("August");
    mnth.push("July");
    mnth.push("June");
    mnth.push("May");
    mnth.push("April");
    mnth.push("March");
    mnth.push("February");
    mnth.push("January");

    const char *delimeter="-";
    char* date=new char;


    time_t     now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char       buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%m-%d", &tstruct);

    date = buf;


    char* token= new char;
    vector<string> dt;

    token=strtok(date,delimeter);
    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        dt.push_back(token);
        token=strtok(NULL,delimeter);
    }

    string monthL,monthM;
    int dayL;
    int monthnum;
    istringstream(dt[0])>>monthnum;
    for(int x=1;x!=monthnum;x++)
        mnth.pop();
    monthL=mnth.top();


    istringstream (dt[1])>>dayL;

    do{month.pop();}while(monthL!=month.top());

    month.pop();
    month.pop();
    month.pop();

    monthM=month.top();

    str=monthL+'-'+
        rec->numToStr(dayL)+'-'+
        monthM+'-'+
        rec->numToStr(dayL);

    int strsize = str.size();
    char* chr = new char;

    for(int x=0;x<strsize;x++)
    {
        chr[x]=str[x];
    }
    return chr;
}
catch(char* ex){system("pause");}
}

ClientInfo* Record::AddClient(string fn, string ln,string xMonthL, int xDayL, string    
xMonthM, int xDayM, double xItemAmt)
{
ClientInfo* newInfo = new ClientInfo();
Record* newRecord = new Record();

newInfo->fName = fn;
newInfo->lName = ln;
newInfo->dayM = xDayM;
newInfo->monthM = xMonthM;
newInfo->dayL = xDayL;
newInfo->monthL = xMonthL;
newInfo->itmAmt = xItemAmt;

if(newInfo->next!=NULL)
{
    newInfo->next = head;
    numOfClients++;
    head = newInfo;
}
else
{
    newInfo->next=NULL;
}

return head;    
}

Record* Record::InitializeRecord()
{
Record* initRec = new Record();
ClientInfo* initClient = new ClientInfo();

ifstream inF;
inF.open("Record.txt");

char* rec;
char* token;
vector<string> v;
int dayL, dayM;
string monthL, monthM;
double itmAmt;

if(inF.good())
{
    do
    {
        rec = new char;
        token = new char;
        inF>>rec;
        token = strtok(rec,"-");
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
            v.push_back(token);
            token = strtok(NULL,"-");
        }

        istringstream(v[2])>>monthL;
        istringstream(v[3])>>dayL;
        istringstream(v[4])>>monthM;
        istringstream(v[5])>>dayM;
        istringstream(v[6])>>itmAmt;
        initRec->AddClient(v[0],v[1],monthL,dayL,monthM,dayM,itmAmt);
        v.erase(v.begin(),v.end());
    }while(!inF.eof());
}

inF.close();
return initRec;
}

void Record::RemoveItem(ClientInfo* h, ClientInfo* rc, string remfname)
{
ClientInfo* head = h;
ClientInfo* temp = rc->next;
if(temp!=NULL)
{
    rc->fName = rc->next->fName;
    rc->lName = rc->next->lName;
    rc->monthL = rc->next->monthL;
    rc->dayL = rc->next->dayL;
    rc->monthM = rc->next->monthM;
    rc->dayM = rc->next->dayM;
    rc->itmAmt = rc->next->itmAmt;

    rc->next = temp->next;
    numOfClients--;
    free(temp);
}
else
{
    head = NULL;
    free(temp);
}
SaveRecord(head);
}

ClientInfo* Record::SearchClient(string n)
{
ClientInfo* current = head;

for(int x=numOfClients-1;current!=NULL;x--)
{
    if(current->lName == n)
        return current;
    else
        current = current->next;
}

return current;
}

string Record::ViewClient()
{
string s;
ClientInfo* itr;
itr = head;
if(numOfClients!=0)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<returnNumOfClients();i++)
    {
        string empty = "";
        int y = i+1;
        s+="\n\n***************\nName: "+itr->fName+" "+itr->lName+"\n-----            
                    ----------\n"+
            "Loan Origination Date: "+numToStr(itr->monthL)+" 
                    "+numToStr(itr->dayL)+
            "\n---------------\n"+"Date Of Maturity: "+numToStr(itr-                       
                    >monthM)+" "+numToStr(itr->dayM)+"\n---------------\n"+
            "Balance: "+numToStr(itr->itmAmt);
        itr = itr->next;
    }

    s.append("\n***************\n\n");
}
else
    s ="There is no recorded client yet.\n\n";

return s;
}

double Record::ComputeBalance(double amount, string mnthL, int dyL, string mnthM, int  
    dyM)
{
try
{
    double INTEREST = 0.04;

    double PENALTY = 0.02;

    stack<string> monthl;
    monthl.push("December");
    monthl.push("November");
    monthl.push("October");
    monthl.push("September");
    monthl.push("August");
    monthl.push("July");
    monthl.push("June");
    monthl.push("May");
    monthl.push("April");
    monthl.push("March");
    monthl.push("February");
    monthl.push("January");
    monthl.push("December");
    monthl.push("November");
    monthl.push("October");
    monthl.push("September");
    monthl.push("August");
    monthl.push("July");
    monthl.push("June");
    monthl.push("May");
    monthl.push("April");
    monthl.push("March");
    monthl.push("February");
    monthl.push("January");


    stack<string> monthm;
    monthm.push("December");
    monthm.push("November");
    monthm.push("October");
    monthm.push("September");
    monthm.push("August");
    monthm.push("July");
    monthm.push("June");
    monthm.push("May");
    monthm.push("April");
    monthm.push("March");
    monthm.push("February");
    monthm.push("January");
    monthm.push("December");
    monthm.push("November");
    monthm.push("October");
    monthm.push("September");
    monthm.push("August");
    monthm.push("July");
    monthm.push("June");
    monthm.push("May");
    monthm.push("April");
    monthm.push("March");
    monthm.push("February");
    monthm.push("January");

    int ml=0;
    int mm=0;

    do{
        monthl.pop();
        mm++;
    }while(mnthL!=monthl.top());

    do
    {
        monthm.pop();
        ml++;
    }while(mnthM!=monthm.top());

    int diff=abs(mm-ml);
    double balance=diff*(amount*(INTEREST+  
                                                 (INTEREST/(pow(INTEREST+1,diff)-1))));

    return balance;
}
catch(double ex){system("pause");}
}

bool Record::CheckExistence(ClientInfo* hx, string fnx, string lnx)
{
ClientInfo *hh;
hh = head;
int t=0;

for(int x=numOfClients; hh!=NULL && x!=0; x--)
{
    if(hh->fName == fnx && hh->lName==lnx)
        t++;
    else
        hh=hh->next;
}

if(t!=0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

int main()
{

Record* rec = new Record();
ClientInfo* info;

Record* samelastrec = new Record();
double amt;
double balance;
int number;
int choose;
char ch;
double principal;
string iLName,iFName;
string nn;
int iDayL,iDayM;
string iMonthL,iMonthM;
string delfname;
rec=rec->InitializeRecord();

again:
system("cls");
cout<<"WELCOME TO JEWELRY PAWNING SYSTEM."<<endl;
cout<<"\n(1)Add Client\n(2)Remove Client\n(3)Search Client\n\n->";

cin>>choose;
Record *find = new Record();
ClientInfo* found;


system("cls");
int search;
char* datelm;
char* token;
vector<string> date;
string nnx; 
switch(choose)
{
case 1:

    system("cls");

    if(rec->returnNumOfClients()!=0 || rec->returnNumOfClients()!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"First Name: ";
        cin>>iFName;
        cout<<"Last name: ";
        cin>>iLName;

        if(!rec->CheckExistence(rec->head,iFName,iLName))
        {
            cout<<"Amount: ";
            cin>>amt;
            datelm=rec->CalculateMaturity();

            token=strtok(datelm, "-");
            while(token!=NULL)
            {
                date.push_back(token);
                token=strtok(NULL, "-");
            }

            istringstream(date[0])>>iMonthL;
            istringstream(date[1])>>iDayL;
            istringstream(date[2])>>iMonthM;
            istringstream(date[3])>>iDayM;

    balance=rec->ComputeBalance(amt,iMonthL,iDayL,iMonthM,iDayM);
            istringstream(rec->numToStr(balance));

    rec->head=rec>AddClient(iFName,iLName,iMonthL,iDayL,iMonthM,iDayM,balance);
            system("pause");
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Member already exist!"<<endl;
            system("pause");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"First Name: ";
        cin>>iFName;
        cout<<"Last name: ";
        cin>>iLName;
        cout<<"Amount: ";
        cin>>amt;
        datelm=rec->CalculateMaturity();

        token=strtok(datelm, "-");
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
            date.push_back(token);
            token=strtok(NULL, "-");
        }

        istringstream(date[0])>>iMonthL;
        istringstream(date[1])>>iDayL;
        istringstream(date[2])>>iMonthM;
        istringstream(date[3])>>iDayM;

        balance=rec->ComputeBalance(amt,iMonthL,iDayL,iMonthM,iDayM);
        istringstream(rec->numToStr(balance));

    rec->head=rec>AddClient(iFName,iLName,iMonthL,iDayL,iMonthM,iDayM,balance);
        system("pause");
    }

    rec->SaveRecord(rec->head);
    goto again;
    break;

case 2:
    system("cls");
    find->head = rec->head;
    cout<<"Enter Last Name: ";
    cin>>iLName;
    samelastrec=new Record();
    samelastrec=samelastrec->FindName(iLName, rec->head);


    if(find->SearchClient(iLName) == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Client not found.\n";
        system("pause");
    }
    else
    {

        found = find->SearchClient(iLName);

        if(samelastrec->returnNumOfClients()>1)
        {
            cout<<samelastrec->ViewClient()<<endl<<endl;


           cout<<"There are "<<samelastrec->numToStr(samelastrec->returnNumOfClients())    
                            <<" Clients with "<<samelastrec->head->lName<<" last name";
            cout<<endl<<"Enter the first name of the client you want to 
                                                                             remove: ";
            cin>>delfname;
            system("cls");

            if(samelastrec->CheckExistence(samelastrec->head,delfname, 
                                                                            iLName))
            {
                cout<<endl<<"Do you want to remove "<<delfname<<" 
                                            <<samelastrec->head->lName<<" ?(Y/N)";
                cin>>ch;

                if(ch=='Y' || ch=='y')
                {
                    rec->RemoveItem(rec->head,found,delfname);
                    cout<<"Client Removed."<<endl;
                    system("cls");

                }
                else if(ch=='N' || ch=='n')
                    goto again;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"The member with "<<delfname<<" does not 
                                    exist."<<endl;
                system("pause");
                goto again;
            }

            system("pause");
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<endl<<samelastrec->ViewClient()<<endl;
            cout<<"Remove Client? [Y/N]: ";
            cin>>ch;

            if(ch=='Y' || ch=='y')
            {
                system("cls");
                rec->RemoveItem(rec->head,found,found->fName);
                cout<<"Client Removed."<<endl;
                system("pause");
            }
            else if(ch=='N' || ch=='n')
                goto again;
        }
    }
    goto again;
    break;

case 3:
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Enter Last Name : ";
    cin>>nnx;

    samelastrec=new Record();
    samelastrec=samelastrec->FindName(nnx, rec->head);
    cout<<samelastrec->ViewClient()<<endl;


    system("pause");
    break;
case 4:
    system("cls");
    cout<<rec->ViewClient();
    system("pause");
    goto again;
    break;

case 5:
    cout<<"Number of clients: "<<rec->numToStr(rec->returnNumOfClients())
                                                                                <<endl;
    system("pause");
    break;
default:
    if(choose!=0)
    {
        cout<<"\n\nInvalid Entry.\n\n";
        system("pause");
        goto again;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n\nTHANK YOU FOR USING THE JEWELRY PAWNING SYSTEM!\n\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
}
goto again;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting these errors.

Please help me debug this error.

Thanks!

Comment: The first thing you need to do is use a debugger and tell us *where* this happens.

Comment: I notice you're using `goto` as well. Jumping around in code is generally unwanted, as it's not structured at all. It's easier to read, maintain, and debug code that uses things like while loops rather than goto.

Comment: `Record::InitializeRecord()` has some nasty business going on, including a `new`ed Client that is never returned nor deleted.  And accessing a vector using `[]` without checking to see how many elements are in the vector.  I'd guess your problem is somewhere in there.

Answer (score 3):

Throughout your code you have sections like this that trash memory you do not own:

```
int strsize = str.size();
char* chr = new char;

for(int x=0;x<strsize;x++)
{
    chr[x]=str[x];
}
return chr;
```

It looks like you don't quite understand how pointers and `new` work. `new char;` allocates enough memory for just one character - typically one byte; so when `x` is larger than 0 in the subsequent loop you're overwriting memory you do not own, leading eventually to a crash. You have a number of sections of code like this. Either allocate the correct amount of memory for the operation (e.g. `new char[strsize]`), or (preferably) use C++ strings instead of character arrays.

(I also note you do not appear to ever free any of the memory you allocate, this will eventually cause problems as you perform more allocations during a run of the program. In general, every use of `new` should be matched by a corresponding use of `delete`).

Comment: how about if the size of the char array is unknown? can it be dynamically implemented?